# Include inheritance constraint in Swift Generic types

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to create a basic Service Locator / DI implementation using Swift and generics. What I want to accomplish is registering *type* and *implementation-type* and have those two constrained in the signature, so that the *implementation-type* is derived from the *type*.

However I cannot seem to come up with the correct syntax (if at all possible). My naive attempt:

```
func register<T, U>(type: T.Type, implementationType: U.Type) where U: T {
    // ...
}
```

This will not compile however, with the message:

```
Type 'U' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'T'
```

Adding the constraint `where T: AnyObject`, does not help.

Is it at all possible to constrain the inheritance in the signature?

Answer (score 0):

A solution.

I image you have some classes, with few of them root of others, customers of your "resister" function.

Set up a void protocol named Root

```
protocol Root {}
```

Conform your root classes to protocol Root

```
extension YourRootClasses: Root {}

eg: 
class A: Root {} ; class B: A {}
class Mainstuff: Root {} ; class SubStuff: MainStuff
```

then you can check the conformance or inheritance of your generic U to Root protocol.

```
func register<T, U>(type: T.Type, implementationType: U.Type) where U: Root {
// ...
}
```

It's true that if you have A -> B -> C and want check C -> B strictly, it doesn't work.