# Swift covariant generic function : placeholder type is a subclass of another

Tags: swift, generics

I have a function that takes two classes as parameters. I'd like the first one to be a subclass of NSObject (pretty straightforward so far), and the second to be a subclass or the same class as the other – how can I express this ?

```swift
class MyClass: NSObject {}
class MySubClass: MyClass {}
myFunction(MyClass.Type, MySubClass.Type)
```

With MyFunction defined as follows:

```swift
func myFunction<T: NSObject>(param1: T.Type, param2: T.Type)
```

Unfortunately, because MyClass and MySubClass are not the same (and my definition of myFunction expects them to be the exact same), the invocation errors with *'(MyClass.Type, MySubClass.Type)' is not convertible to '(MyClass.Type, MyClass.Type)'*.

How to express the fact that the type of the second parameter of myFunction needs not be the same as the first, but merely `__kindof`, as one would've written it in Objective-C ?

EDIT : 
As it seems, my question is not clear. 
The following is not enough : 
`func myFunction<T:NSObject,U:NSObject>(param1: T.Type, param2: U.Type)`
... because it allows me to invoke it as `myFunction(param1: MyClass.Type, param2: AnotherClass.Type)` with AnotherClass defined as `class AnotherClass : NSObject`. In that case, AnotherClass is outside of MyClass' inheritance hierarchy.

That's why I gave the example of `__kindof`, which expresses just that (in ObjC) – that is, covariant generics.

Comment: Interesting, I'd expect `func myFunction<T:NSObject,U:T>(param1: T.Type, param2: U.Type)` to work, since `T` is guaranteed to be a class type, but it results in the error `Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'T'`. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626563/include-inheritance-constraint-in-swift-generic-types), no answer though.

Comment: `func myFunction<T:MyClass,U:MyClass>(param1: T.Type, param2: U.Type)` ?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yeah, that's too bad. For some reason, every time I try to work with Swift I end up either going too far for the type system or discovering a bug in it... which case does this fall in, in your opinion ?

Comment: @meggar not generic enough, I need to be able to invoke `myFunction` *also* on, say, MyOtherClass and MyOtherSubclass with MyOtherSubclass inheriting from MyOtherClass – that wouldn't work with your solution, unfortunately

Comment: @Perceval not sure if it's a bug or rather a not yet implemented feature... In this case, the compiler should definitely be able to infer that `T` is a class due to the inheritance from another class. The other question I linked is a harder one to crack though, since there the compiler has no information to deduce that `T` is a class or protocol type

Comment: For anyone interested in the issue, I've created a Swift compiler bug for this: [SR-9780](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9780) to get an official answer of whether this is actually a bug or just a shortcoming of the current type system/compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need or not? There is no problem to run it.

```
class MyClass: NSObject {}
class MySubClass: MyClass {}

func myFunction<T: NSObject>(param1: T.Type, param2: T.Type){
print("OK")
}
myFunction(param1: MyClass.self, param2: MySubClass.self as MyClass.Type)
```

or

```
myFunction(param1: type(of: MyClass()), param2: type(of: MySubClass()))
```

Comment: You can still call that function with two instances of the parent class, which doesn't solve the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by the Swift compiler. You can track the status of the implementation of this feature under [SR-5213](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5213).

Sadly I wouldn't expect it to happen soon as per the comment of one of the Apple developers on the issue:

> To be honest, I suspect this will not get much traction from us implementers any time soon because it's not a very common use case—the value gain just doesn't justify the work required in the near-term.