# How to allow a generic collection to perform under the hood conversion in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I am implementing a generic collection and I would like to make its usage with types/protocol hierarchy more convenient. I stumbled on the following question.

How one does implement a collection

```
class SpecialSet<ObjectType> {
```

Such that given two types `B : A` one can perform implicite conversion of `SpecialSet<B>` into `SpecialSet<A>` ?

---

I am suprised but I wasn't able to find any documentation explaining this simple concept that indeed exist for the Array collection. This swift code is indeed valid:

```swift
let b = [B(), B(), B()]
let a: [A] = b
```

I probably do not used the right vocabulary in my searches.

I tried to define a constructor as follow but it seams not possible to enforce inheritance between two generic.

```swift
  init<T>(_ specialSet: SpecialSet<T>) where T: ObjectType {
```

Comment: Check [Swift covariant generic function : placeholder type is a subclass of another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54407709/4667835). Sadly this is simply not supported by the Swift compiler at the moment.

Comment: @DávidPásztorThanks. It looks like it explain why the `T: ObjectType` constraints doesn't work. But is their an over approach to achieve this "implicit casting" effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It has always been impossible.](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html#comment-e1defaef8e71a2dcc471b51f67725737)

> Swift generics are normally invariant, but the Swift standard library
>   collection types — even though those types appear to be regular
>   generic types — use some sort of magic inaccessible to mere mortals
>   that lets them be covariant.

Potential workaround. ‍♂️

```swift
protocol Subclass: AnyObject {
  associatedtype Superclass
}

extension B: Subclass {
  typealias Superclass = A
}

class SpecialSet<Object>: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
  required init(arrayLiteral _: Object...) { }
  init<T: Subclass>(_: SpecialSet<T>) where T.Superclass == Object { }
}

let specialSetB: SpecialSet = [B(), B()]
let specialSetA = SpecialSet<A>(specialSetB)
```

Comment: I added a workaround idea that's probably similar to what the compiler gets to generate for standard library collections.