# Why checking whether generic type is an Array of type Any always fails

Tags: ios, swift, generics

In my generic method I want to check if `T` is an array. During testing I'm calling the method for `T` type of `[SPTArtist]`. If I print the type of `T` it shows:

```
Array<SPTArtist>
```

And if I check if it's an Array of SPTArtist it returns `true`.

```
print(T.self is Array<SPTArtist>.Type) //true
```

But the code

```
print(T.self is Array<Any>.Type) //false
```

prints `false`

Shouldn't it be true as all objects are `Any`?

Comment: I already answered this earlier. Watch your comments!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift generics. How to check if the type of Array's Element inherits from other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223349/swift-generics-how-to-check-if-the-type-of-arrays-element-inherits-from-other)

Comment: I don't think it helps in my situation

Comment: I think it’s a complete explanation. What do you find lacking?

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you can assign any value (not just objects) to a variable of type `Any` and you can add any value to an array whose element type is `Any`, it is not true that `[Any]` and `[SPTArtist]` are the same type.

You can see this from the following example:

```
var someArray = [Any]()
var someOtherArray = [SPTArtist]()

let artist = SPTArtist()

someArray.append(artist)      // OK
someOtherArray.append(artist) // OK

someArray.append(1)           // OK
someOtherArray.append(1)      // Error
```

Your test is checking to see if the type of `T` is literally `[Any]`, not if it is "an array".

If you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+check+if+variable+is+array) you can find several variations on checking to see if a variable is an array.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033993/swift-check-if-value-is-of-type-array-of-any-type) that extends `Array` with an empty protocol seems like a reasonable approach.

You could add a type constraint so that it only applies to arrays of your type:

```
protocol ArrayType {}
extension Array: ArrayType where Element == SPTArtist {}  

func isArray() -> Bool {
    return T.self is ArrayType.Type  // Returns true iff T is [SPTArtist]
}
```

Comment: Explain that you understand the covariance problem or this will haunt you to the grave and beyond!

Comment: I am not sure which part you are specifically referring to.  The problem here isn't related to covariance, since `Any` is not a super type.  The OP's problem is that `[Any]` is a specific type, i.e. it is literally "an Array of `Any`" which is different to `[SPTArtist]`.  Now of course an `[SPTArtist]` can contain elements of some subclass of `SPTArtist`, but that doesn't change the fact the array must be an array of `SPTArtist` for the `isArray` function to return `true`.  An array of `SPTArtistSubClass` won't return `true` unless the extension is also applied to that element type